# The performance of the classifier went bad after adding extra two features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I'm solving a classification problem using 10 features and logistic regression. The performance of the classifier is fine when I use the 10 features only, however when adding another 2 features, the performance gets a little worse.

When I use the 2 features alone with the classifier I get a performance as good as using the 10 features.

Now my question is why would the performance gets worse when I use the 12 features combined?! Since using the 10 features with the classifier alone and the 2 features with the classifier alone gave almost identical performance, then why combining them would cause a problem? I would expect the performance to increase or at least be the same!

Edit:

is it possible that this is a 'curse of dimensionality'?

Comment: Did you try to vary regularization parameter?

Comment: What is your data? What is your sample size? How much are the features correlated?

Comment: @Barmaley.exe I'm using scikit-learn so I can't really play with regularization parameters.

Comment: @Tim I'm not looking to really solve the issue, rather I'm looking to understand what are the possible reasons that could cause the classifier to suffer from this issue given the described situation.

Comment: @JackTwain, why so? sklearn's `LogisticRegression` has `penalty` and `C` parameters, which can be tuned using `GridSearchCV`, for example.

Comment: You absolutely can play with regularization parameters in scikit-learn logistic regression http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_l1_l2_sparsity.html. Have you actually looked at how the coefficients change in your three cases of regression? That's important to understand.

Comment: By what metric are you evaluating performance?

Comment: Please post data to reproduce behaviour.

Comment: I used SVM with a bag-of-words model to classify Stack Overflow questions. When The labels are each close reason, the accuracy is 99.98%. But when I added a new label, "non-closed questions," and training data to go along with it, the accuracy drops to 39%.

Comment: I think it is not clear if the problem is overfitting or the features are not good features. The best way to study if the problem is overfitting or not is to compare train and validation performance in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of having too many variables in your model is called over-fitting. In predictive modeling, the idea is to use the data at hand to discover the trends that exist and that can be generalized to future data. By including variables in your model that have some minor, non-significant effect you are abandoning this idea. What you are doing is considering the specific trends in your specific sample that are only there because of random noise instead of a true, underlying trend. In other words, a model with too many variables fits the noise rather than discovering the signal.

As an exaggerated example, consider a model where $\hat{Y}_i=Y_i$. In other words, the predicted value equals the observed value. In this example we have an extreme case of over-fitting (in fact, we have a perfect fit). However, we are not discovering the general trends that the data is generated from.

When you have more variables in the model, $SSE=\sum_i^n(Y_i-\hat{Y}_i)^2$ is necessarily decreasing which means, on average, you are getting closer to the exaggerated $\hat{Y}_i=Y_i$ example.

It might seem weird that we want our predicted value to be close to the observed value, *but not too close*. This is why many people like cross-validation techniques to help with model selection and it's one of the reasons why some people will say "statistics is an art not a science".

Comment: so this is also the curse of dimensionality?

Comment: Same question: so this is also the curse of dimensionality?

Comment: I would not call this phenomenon the curse of dimensionality because you can have an overfit model in low dimensions. Rereading the question now (it's been a long time), it seems to me that OP has a set of two variables that have the same information in them as the set of ten variables. So combining the variables is redundant.